# Imagem não é exibida ao recarregar a página

Tags: javascript

Meu código faz com que, quando eu role a página para baixo, seja mostrado o logo. E quando rolo de volta, ele esconde.

Acontece que quando estou no meio da página, com ele ativo, e reinicio a página - refresh - o navegador me joga lá pro meio da página onde eu estava e o logo não aparece. Mesmo estando quase no fim do site. Só depois que eu do um toque no *scroll* que ele exibe.

Como resolver isso?

Meu código:

```
$(document).bind('ready load scroll resize', function() {
      if($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $(".logoHeader").addClass("logoHeaderHide");
        $(".logoNav").addClass("logoNavShow");
      } else {
        $(".logoHeader").removeClass("logoHeaderHide");
        $(".logoNav").removeClass("logoNavShow");
      }
});
```

Comment: Troque o `document` por `window`... o único evento escutado pelo `document` na lista que vc colocou é o `scroll`, ou seja, os outros (ready, load e resize) estão lá sem nenhum efeito.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Recomendo trocar o método `.bind()` (obsoleto) por `.on()`.

Quanto ao código, você listou 4 eventos a serem escutados pelo objeto `document`:

- ready
- load
- scroll
- resize

Desses 4, apenas o evento `scroll` é escutado pelo `document`, ou seja, seu `if` só será executado quando você fizer scroll na página. Os outros 3 eventos serão ignorados.

No entanto, ao recarregar a página e o navegador te joga pro ponto onde estava e o evento scroll é disparado, e deveria executar o `if`(?). Pelo menos isso deveria funcionar.

Outra coisa é que não existe evento `ready` no JavaScript. Existe o `.ready()` do jQuery, que é um método. Ou seja, o `ready` da lista não significa nada.

Seu problema é resolvido apenas trocando o `$(document)` por `$(window)` e retirando o `ready` que não tem nenhuma função, ficando assim:

```
$(window).bind('scroll load resize', function() {...
```

Ou usando `.on()` (preferível se estiver usando versão 1.7 ou superior):

```
$(window).on('scroll load resize', function() {...
```

Comment: Funcionou, valeu! E agradeço pela explicação também.

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa verificar a posição do *scroll* quando concluir o carregamento do DOM.

Você pode duplicar o bloco `if/else`, mas uma forma pouco mais correta é criar uma função para tal.

Veja meu exemplo, <strike>dentro do reproduzível do seu código</strike>:

```js
function logoScroll() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $(".logoHeader").addClass("logoHeaderHide");
        $(".logoNav").addClass("logoNavShow");
    } else {
        $(".logoHeader").removeClass("logoHeaderHide");
        $(".logoNav").removeClass("logoNavShow");
    }
}

$(document).on('scroll resize', function() {
    logoScroll();
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    logoScroll();
});
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}
div.content {
    background-color: #babaca;
    height: 4096px;
}
div.logoNav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    display: none;
}
div.logoNav.logoNavShow {
    display: block;
}
div.logoNav > img {
    max-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <body>
        <div class="content">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </div>
        <div class="logoNav">
            <img src="http://pigment.github.io/fake-logos/logos/large/color/fast-banana.png">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```